# How to reset a component's props in VueJS upon reload?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component in VueJS that displays a data table based off an array of objects. The component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="table">
    <p class="title">Data:</p>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="imported_data">
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{props.item.name}}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{props.item.age}}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    imported_data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      { text: "Name", value: "name" },
      { text: "Age", value: "age" }
    ]
  })
};
</script>
```

I can render this component by doing `<DataTableView :imported_data="this.dataset"/>`, where `this.dataset` is an array of objects that populates my data table. My issue is when I go to reinitialize my component with another dataset, the new dataset just appends to the old dataset, it doesn't overwrite the old dataset with the new dataset. How can I make it so that my `imported_data` prop is reset when I put in new data?

Edit:

The data in `imported_data` is retrieved from the backend via a simple GET request:

```
axios
    .get("http://localhost:8888/getData")
    .then((res) => {
        this.dataset = res.data
    })
```

I have a button on the page that gets new data from my backend again, but the 'new' data is appending my 'old' data. The DataTableView component is loaded alongside the button, but isn't shown until `this.imported_data` is populated via a `v-if` conditional.

Comment: how are you doing that re initialization?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to populate the dataset..

Comment: shouldn't it be `<DataTableView :imported_data="dataset" />` without `this.`?

Comment: @bhaskar, more info on how the data is retrieved was added above.

Comment: @YongQuan I used `this.` because I already declared an empty array in my data function. The DataTableView component and the button that contacts my backend to get the data is loaded on the same page and the DataTableView component isn't shown until `this.imported_data` is populated, via a `v-if` conditional.

Comment: what did you get if you do `console.log(this.dataset)` after `this.dataset = res.data`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I found the root of the problem, my backend was appending the datasets, Vue had nothing to do with it! Thanks for your help!